# How to figure out what DC power jack I need?

Tags: power, pcb, dc, monitor

so my monitor's power jack has burned up and was wondering if there is anyway to identify what jack I need to replace it?

On the PCB it says J101 but Google is not coming up with anything.

[image: Burned PCB Part]
[image: Power Jack]

Comment: measure the inner diameter and outer diameter, and also the length of the plug side (but length seems to matter less usually)

Comment: J101 is simply the reference number used to identify that particular connector on the schematics and parts lists. It's not a manufacturer's part number.

Comment: Pictures make it hard to determine. Not because they wouldn't provide detail but because it's not possible to give us a good perspective where we would be satisfied with complete confidence about what you need help with. @user3528438 has good advice there. That power supply is probably something you can pick up at a computer store.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have more pictures here https://imgur.com/a/yiE25 but I will try measuring it. How do I determine the amp? I see some stores selling 2.5A and 3.5A, here http://www.cui.com/catalog/components/connectors/dc-power/jacks/1.0-mm-center-pin

Comment: I'm concerned there's a deeper issue than a burnt pin on a power jack. I recommend more investigation.

Comment: if there's a RadioShack by you, they have a "warden's keyring" of plug pigtails you can use to match up the proper size jack.

Comment: I use a set of metric drill bits (0.5 mm steps) to gauge the ID of the plug on the lead.

Comment: I think the issue is visible on other pictures. The board has a very poor soldering job, slots are not filled. Any usual mechanical stress (from plugged cable) might cause the solder joint to become cracked/loose, contact resistance goes up, and eventually it burns out.

Comment: Yeah guys I think this is a power jack issue, not anything to do with any other part of the board,  because before this to get it working I had to use sellotape to keep the power connector in a proper place to make contact. I should of just fixed it then but I made it worse and it burned up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commonly accepted name of this part is "barrel jack". The power jacks come in variety of sizes, often characterized by pin diameter (Inner Diameter), and OD (outer size). This particular part looks very like having pin diameter of 2.5mm and the standard OD size of 5.5mm, although the exact measurements may differ by a notch. The part shown is very similar to this DIGI-KEY part,
[image]

Important part is to determine whether this is a 2.1 mm jack, or 2.5 mm one.

Answer (score 4):

I would guess it's a 2.5mm DC power jack, but it could be 2mm. Both come in varying shapes and mounting styles, so either way you'll have to take some measurements to know for sure.

I think the bigger question is: why did the jack burn up? Replacing the jack is ultimately not likely to be your solution. You may want to use some alligator clips and a bench supply, to make sure the monitor still works before going through the effort of replacing the DC port. Check for hot downstream components and look for bulging capacitors. If there are onboard power regulators, check their output levels.